# Python 3.6 - reading the the values of rows from two lists after a conditional statement

Tags: python, count

Hi here is my code that looks for values that repeat 3 or more times in list a:

```
a = ['1','1','1','2','2','3']
b = ['4','5','1','7','8','4']

d = [item for item in a if a.count(item) >= 3]

print(d)
# ['1', '1', '1']
```

So my question is how can I also read the corresponding values in list b. Also list a and b are always the same size. My desired output should be:

```
output: [['1', '1', '1'], ['4', '5', '1']]
```

thank you!

Comment: Maybe not that pythonic, but you still can do the same loop for b like this `e = [item for item in b if b.count(item) >= 3]` and add the results to a new list `results = list()` and then `results.append(d)` and of course `results.append(e)` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using zip:

```
>>> list(zip(*[(ai, bi) for ai, bi in zip(a, b) if a.count(ai) >= 3]))
[('1', '1', '1'), ('4', '5', '1')]
```

Comment: Hi, how can I read the output if it is zipped. I get this: <zip at 0x5aae738>

Comment: If you truly need the ouput as a list you can use `list(zip(*[(ai, bi) for ai, bi in zip(a, b) if a.count(ai) >= 3]))`, with that said for most applications the iterator should be enough

Comment: Unfortunately, especially someone who is new to python can use this approach, as it does what it is supposed to do, but he/she will never really understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use enumerate:

```
d = [(item,c[1][i]) for i,item in enumerate(c[0]) if c[0].count(item) >= 3]
```

Then you can zip them together

```
d = zip(*d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) like below:

```
import itertools


a = ['1', '1', '6', '2', '1', '3']
b = ['4', '5', '1', '7', '8', '4']

a_items = [item for item in a if a.count(item) >= 3]
b_items = list(itertools.compress(b, (i in set(a_items) for i in a)))

res = [a_items, b_items]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[['1', '1', '1'], ['4', '5', '8']]
```